# submit form data via html5 data- attribute

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

i have a question about data- attribute. Atm i have a button like this

```
button.btn.btn-link.btn-form type="button" data={form: {method: 'POST', url: url, 'confirmation' => 'Are you sure you want to ....?'}}
```

works fine but now i have some change in method and gotta send a param when call method. I can do it via javascript and ajax, but form parameter has only 1 value so i want to keep it as simple as it can. Tried many ways but nothing sent but url and method

Can we send form parameter via html5 data- attribute?